# Trying to get PyCharm to help me check dimensions of arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm writing a small real-analysis framework that to deal with functions on R^m, their derivatives, projections, coordinate functions, etc.

I'm doing this in PyCharm, and I'd like to see if it's possible to have PyCharm help me make sure that I have dimensions right when I create new functions or compose/project/differentiate/etc.  For example, for a function from R^n to R^m, the Jacobian should be mxn, and so on.

I'm trying to use type-hinting for this.  At this point, I'm not even trying to get np arrays in the typing scheme, though that would be nice, because the inputs and outputs to everything are in fact of type `np.ndarray`.

What I've tried (see below for a simple example) doesn't work at all, PyCharm doesn't complain in the place where I want it to.  I don't know if anything like this is even possible, but any hints or advice would be appreciated.

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, NewType

import numpy as np

N = TypeVar("N")
M = TypeVar("M")
K = TypeVar("K")

NPVector = Generic[N]

# These other ways of doing it don't work either
#
# NPVector = NewType("NPVector", Generic[N])
#
# class NPVector(np.ndarray, Generic[N]):
#    pass


class VectorMapping(ABC, Generic[M, N]):

    @abstractmethod
    def apply(self, x: NPVector[M]) -> NPVector[N]:
        pass


class ComposedMapping(VectorMapping[M, N], Generic[M, N, K]):

    def __init__(self, first: VectorMapping[M, K], second: VectorMapping[K, N]):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def apply(self, x: NPVector[M]) -> NPVector[N]:
        return self.second.apply(self.first.apply(x))

    def apply_wrong(self, x: NPVector[M]) -> NPVector[N]:
        # here is where I want PyCharm to complain
        return self.first.apply(self.second.apply(x))
```

Comment: Why not just check the dimensions at the start of functions? `numpy` functions do that all the time.

Comment: Yes, I do that, but I want to be able to catch more bugs while coding rather than at runtime.

Comment: During coding, how is `pycharm` (or what ever) supposed to check the dimensions of an array?  The dimensions of an array are given by its `shape` and `ndim` properties.  Admittedly I've only given a `type-hinting` a cursory look, so there might be tricks that I'm not aware of.

Comment: @hpaulj PyCharm uses its own linter implementation...In some other languages linters do verify array dimensions. I'm not sure, but from memory I don't recall the 484 series of peps saying anything about array dimensions...It's an interesting question.

Comment: @hpaulj A lot of information about dimensions and even content of arrays is available at compile time (or "IDE time"). E.g. if `x` is a matrix and we compute `y=x.T@x` then at compile time we know that `y` is a matrix, `y` is square, `y` is symmetric, and `y` is positive (semi)-definite.

Comment: That depends on the shape (and dtype) of `x`. 1d, 2d, 3+d etc.  Yes, given `x.shape` I could predict the shape of `y`  but can that be programed into pycharm without encoding a numpy simulation?

Comment: E.g. `np.ones(n)` has shape `n`.  With type hinting and type inference, PyCharm can know if `n` is type `int` or `Tuple[int, int]`, etc.  PyCharm could also know that `x` and `x+1` both have the same shape.  Also, with type hinting, it should in principle be possible to tell PyCharm at the start of a function that `x` is 2d, and PyCharm could then infer shapes of other arrays computed from `x`.  So if I type-hinted `f` to take a 2d array to a 1d array, and in my code `f` returned `x.T @ x`, PyCharm could warn be that, based on the input type specified, this is actually a 2d array.